# SSH connect from one virtual machine on a host to another machine on another host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

I have two laptops connected to the same WIFI network. I have created Ubuntu virtual machines on both. I would like to connect those two virtual machines with each other via SSH. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Install and enable SSH server on Virtual machine A:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

### 2. Validate that the SSH service has started on Virtual machine A:

```
sudo systemctl status ssh
```

### 3. Now from Virtual machine B connect using:

```
ssh user@ip
```